Left Justified Above Caption in hvfloats
So far I love the hvfloat package, as it truly eases the placement of image and captions.
But I have a problem getting formatting requirements right:

Captions should hang and indent the caption text by a full caption label width (easy to configure) and should always be left-justified to the text column
Images, if small enough, should be left-justified with the hanging indent (some manual work is needed here, but I can manage that)

Using xcoffin I could get the second requirement, unfortunately the first is a bit cumbersome, as short captions get centered:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcoffins}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hvfloat}

\newcommand{\hangindentmargin}{\caption@hangindent}

\hvFloatSet{
  capPos=top, %Damit das Ganze eingehangen ist.
  capWidth=0.999,%capVPos=top,
  capFormat={format=hang}
}

%%% Aufriss um den Hängenden Einzug zu verbessern;

%%% Global: Särge für das Bild, den Linken Abstand und den Rechten Abstand, sowie den enthaltenden Sarg
\NewCoffin\LinksRand
\NewCoffin\BildInhalt
\NewCoffin\RechtsRand

\newcommand{\prepareFigure}[1]{%    
\SetHorizontalCoffin\BildInhalt{#1}%
\SetHorizontalCoffin\LinksRand{\figureformat\captionformat}%
\SetHorizontalCoffin\LinksRand{\hspace*{\CoffinWidth\LinksRand}}%
\SetHorizontalCoffin\RechtsRand{\hspace*{\dimexpr\textwidth-\CoffinWidth\LinksRand-\CoffinWidth\BildInhalt}\relax}%
\JoinCoffins\LinksRand[r,b]\BildInhalt[l,b]%
\JoinCoffins\LinksRand[r,b]\RechtsRand[l,b]%
\savebox{\hvOBox}{\TypesetCoffin\LinksRand}
}

\NewDocumentCommand\tudFloat{O{h} m +m +m m}{
  \prepareFigure{#3}%
  \hvFloat[floatPos=#1]{#2}{\usebox\hvOBox}{#4}{#5}%
}

\begin{document}


% The Caption is centered, because the caption text is so short
\tudFloat{figure}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}}{I am a short caption}{fig:0}

% Here the caption is correct, but only because the caption text is long enough
\tudFloat{figure}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}}{I am a very very very very very very long, and paragraph breaking caption, that is as long as it needs to be to break the line!}{fig:1}

\end{document}

Is this special formatting possible with hvFloat while preserving as much configurability?

KOMA script has the option captions=nooneline to deactivate centring short captions and handle them like long captions:
\documentclass[captions=nooneline]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcoffins}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hvfloat}

\newcommand{\hangindentmargin}{\caption@hangindent}

\hvFloatSet{
  capPos=top, %Damit das Ganze eingehangen ist.
  capWidth=0.999,%capVPos=top,
  capFormat={format=hang}
}

%%% Aufriss um den Hängenden Einzug zu verbessern;

%%% Global: Särge für das Bild, den Linken Abstand und den Rechten Abstand, sowie den enthaltenden Sarg
\NewCoffin\LinksRand
\NewCoffin\BildInhalt
\NewCoffin\RechtsRand

\newcommand{\prepareFigure}[1]{%    
\SetHorizontalCoffin\BildInhalt{#1}%
\SetHorizontalCoffin\LinksRand{\figureformat\captionformat}%
\SetHorizontalCoffin\LinksRand{\hspace*{\CoffinWidth\LinksRand}}%
\SetHorizontalCoffin\RechtsRand{\hspace*{\dimexpr\textwidth-\CoffinWidth\LinksRand-\CoffinWidth\BildInhalt}\relax}%
\JoinCoffins\LinksRand[r,b]\BildInhalt[l,b]%
\JoinCoffins\LinksRand[r,b]\RechtsRand[l,b]%
\savebox{\hvOBox}{\TypesetCoffin\LinksRand}
}

\NewDocumentCommand\tudFloat{O{h} m +m +m m}{
  \prepareFigure{#3}%
  \hvFloat[floatPos=#1]{#2}{\usebox\hvOBox}{#4}{#5}%
}

\begin{document}


% The Caption is centered, because the caption text is so short
\tudFloat{figure}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}}{I am a short caption}{fig:0}

% Here the caption is correct, but only because the caption text is long enough
\tudFloat{figure}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}}{I am a very very very very very very long, and paragraph breaking caption, that is as long as it needs to be to break the line!}{fig:1}

\end{document}


